# Почему Number("e") не возвращает NaN в if statement?

Tags: javascript

Есть исходные данные в задаче:

```
    var pin = "12345e", arr = [];
    arr = pin.split("");
```

Почему в следующем if statement мы получаем "This is a number!"?

```
    if (Number(arr[5]) == NaN) {
      console.log("This is not a number!");
    } else {
      console.log("This is a number!");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что по аналогии с SQL NULL проверка `NaN === NaN` всегда возвращает `false`. Для проверки на равенство`NaN` нужно использовать функцию `isNaN()`

```js
var pin = "12345e",
  arr = [];
arr = pin.split("");
if (isNaN(Number(arr[5]))) {
  console.log("This is not a number!");
} else {
  console.log("This is a number!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> А значение NaN по стандарту устроено так, что сравнения ==, <, >, <=, >= и даже === с ним возвращают false.

Ref: [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/comparison#%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-undefined)